# operation not permitted error npm while running lerna bootstrap -- hoist command on windows

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, lerna

Whenever I am running `lerna bootstrap --hoist` or `lerna bootstrap` I am getting the following error on my windows machine.

I have already tried `npm login` and force cleaned the npm cache but nothing seems to be working.

```
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\Devfolio_work\ethglobal-devfolio\node_modules\.staging\typescript-ebd093cf\lib\typescriptServices.js'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\Devfolio_work\ethglobal-devfolio\node_modules\.staging\typescript-ebd093cf\lib\typescriptServices.js']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'E:\Devfolio_work\ethglobal-devfolio\node_modules\.staging\typescript-ebd093cf\lib\typescriptServices.js'
npm ERR!      errno: -4048,
npm ERR!      code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!      path:
npm ERR!       'E:\\Devfolio_work\\ethglobal-devfolio\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-ebd093cf\\lib\\typescriptServices.js' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'E:\\Devfolio_work\\ethglobal-devfolio\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-ebd093cf\\lib\\typescriptServices.js\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path:
npm ERR!    'E:\\Devfolio_work\\ethglobal-devfolio\\node_modules\\.staging\\typescript-ebd093cf\\lib\\typescriptServices.js',
npm ERR!   parent: 'root' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-01-09T16_55_24_342Z-debug.log
```

lerna.json

```
{
  "packages": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "version": "independent"
}
```

### My Environment

`lerna --version`  3.5.1

`npm --version`   6.4.1

`node --version`  10.5.0

OS  Version

Windows 10  1709

Comment: maybe you should start a bounty. This problem has not been answered since very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution; it seems to be an issue with Windows. Just run the command in an admin command prompt in your current working directory and it would work.

Answer (score 0):

This might have something to do with local vs. global installation of lerna.
For me it helps to run `lerna bootstrap`, wait for the `EPERM` error, close the terminal and run `lerna bootstrap` again.

Another thing that might work is to run `lerna clean`.

Also watch out for any running scripts - that can lock up some dependencies making you unable to remove them without admin rights. Especially watch scripts.

I'm on Windows using git bash.